# Simple k-means algorithm in Python

Tags: python, k-means

The following is a very simple implementation of the k-means algorithm.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)

DIM = 2
N = 2000
num_cluster = 4
iterations = 3

x = np.random.randn(N, DIM)
y = np.random.randint(0, num_cluster, N)

mean = np.zeros((num_cluster, DIM))
for t in range(iterations):
    for k in range(num_cluster):
        mean[k] = np.mean(x[y==k], axis=0)
    for i in range(N):
        dist = np.sum((mean - x[i])**2, axis=1)
        pred = np.argmin(dist)
        y[i] = pred

for k in range(num_cluster):
    plt.scatter(x[y==k,0], x[y==k,1])
plt.show()
```

Here are two example outputs the code produces:

[image]

[image]

The first example (`num_cluster = 4`) looks as expected. The second example (`num_cluster = 11`) however shows only on cluster which is clearly not what I wanted. The code works depending on the number of classes I define and the number of iterations.

So far, I couldn't find the bug in the code. Somehow the clusters disappear but I don't know why.

Does anyone see my mistake?

Comment: How to recreate second example?

Comment: @FilipMłynarski For `num_cluster = 11` for example, the code does not work anymore.

Comment: Did you check if the clusters are empty any way other than the scatter plot?
I don't know what you expect to happen when the data is actually only one cluster, but I'm assuming you're getting one huge cluster and lots of tiny clusters covered by the dominant class in the scatter plot.

Comment: @ShlomiF I really end up having only one cluster. Should k-means not produce `k` clusters as defined?

Comment: The problem is likely if a cluster goes empty, you get lots of "nan" distances.

In one iteration there are one less clusters, then the next the mean of that cluster comes as nan, then the distances are nans, then I guess the argmin becomes some default, say 0 for each.

(For reproduction I just had to change the seed to 1.)

Comment: @brezniczky How can I prevent that? Or is that the way the k-means algorithm works?

Comment: I think you could delete the clusters that turn to empty for example (and either update N or just iterate through those in the list), on the other hand I'll have to check the standard algorithm pseudocode to comment on how it behaves by the book (and I might not find out! you best give it a look yourself too ;) ).

Comment: That's because of the line "mean[k] = np.mean(x[y==k], axis=0)"  -  the mean of nothing is a dodgy creature. (I definitely have seen nans due to my debug print()s.)

Comment: The Elements of Statistical Learning is not explicit about the initialization step. Under the next link https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-treat-%E2%80%9CK-means-an-empty-cluster%E2%80%9D you'll find that some recommend sampling from the actual points as starting centroids that 'may' help.

Comment: Sorry - in my above comment I didn't mean to update N but the number of clusters i.e. num_cluster. Pardon :) I'll try to fabricate an answer too.

Comment: Looking at [scikit.learns](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#k-means]) explanation may be helpful.  The initialization of the centroids can have a huge effect on convergence, and the final clusters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem that there are NaN's entering the picture.
Using a seed=1, iterations=2, the number of clusters reduce from the initial 4 to effectively 3. In the next iteration this technically plummets to 1.

The NaN mean coordinates of the problematic centroid then result in weird things. To rule out those problematic clusters which became empty, one (possibly a bit too lazy) option is to set the related coordinates to Inf, thereby making it a "more distant than any other" point than those still in the game (as long as the 'input' coordinates cannot be Inf).
The below snippet is a quick illustration of that and a few debug messages that I used to peek into what was going on:

```
[...]
for k in range(num_cluster):
    mean[k] = np.mean(x[y==k], axis=0)
    # print mean[k]
    if any(np.isnan(mean[k])):
        # print "oh no!"
        mean[k] = [np.Inf] * DIM
[...]
```

With this modification the posted algorithm seems to work in a more stable fashion (i.e. I couldn't break it so far).

Please also see the [Quora link](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-treat-%E2%80%9CK-means-an-empty-cluster%E2%80%9D) also mentioned among the comments about the split opinions, and the book "The Elements of Statistical Learning" for [example here](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf) - the algorithm is not too explicitly defined there either in the relevant respect.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting one cluster because there really is only one cluster.
There's nothing in your code to avoid clusters disappearing, and the truth is that this will happen also for 4 clusters but after more iterations.
I ran your code with 4 clusters and 1000 iterations and they all got swallowed up in the one big and dominant cluster.
Think about it, your large cluster passes a critical point, and just keeps growing because other points are gradually becoming closer to it than to their previous mean.
This will not happen in the case that you reach an equilibrium (or stationary) point, in which nothing moves between clusters. But it's obviously a bit rare, and more rare the more clusters you're trying to estimate.

---

A clarification: The same thing can happen also when there are 4 "real" clusters and you're trying to estimate 4 clusters. But that would mean a rather nasty initialization and can be avoided by intelligently aggregating multiple randomly seeded runs.
There are also common "tricks" like taking the initial means to be far apart, or at the centers of different pre-estimated high density locations, etc. But that's starting to get involved, and you should read more deeply about k-means for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

K-means is also pretty sensitive to initial conditions. That said, k-means can and will drop clusters (but dropping to one is weird). In your code, you assign random clusters to the points.

Here's the problem: if I take several random subsamples of your data, they're going to have about the same mean point. Each iteration, the very similar centroids will be close to each other and more likely to drop.

Instead, I changed your code to pick `num_cluster` number of points in your data set to use as the initial centroids (higher variance). This seems to produce more stable results (didn't observe the dropping to one cluster behavior over several dozen runs):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

DIM = 2
N = 2000
num_cluster = 11
iterations = 3

x = np.random.randn(N, DIM)
y = np.zeros(N)
# initialize clusters by picking num_cluster random points
# could improve on this by deliberately choosing most different points
for t in range(iterations):
    if t == 0:
        index_ = np.random.choice(range(N),num_cluster,replace=False)
        mean = x[index_]
    else:
        for k in range(num_cluster):
            mean[k] = np.mean(x[y==k], axis=0)
    for i in range(N):
        dist = np.sum((mean - x[i])**2, axis=1)
        pred = np.argmin(dist)
        y[i] = pred

for k in range(num_cluster):
    fig = plt.scatter(x[y==k,0], x[y==k,1])
plt.show()
```

[image: Ran a few dozen times with consistent results]

Comment: It should be noted: more stable per run, but I'm assuming not very consistent between runs.

Comment: K-means isn't guaranteed to find the same clusters. You can run it several times (and other algorithms) and find which points are most often grouped together for more robust clustering, but that's outta scope of this question I think.

Comment: Of course. What I was alluding to (and maybe should have said explicitly) was the fact the even disregarding k-means inherent non-deterministic nature, no well defined clustering exist in such a scenario and so the fact that you manage to "keep all the clusters" is mute. One aspect of this is the _very high_ inconsistency you'll get. As opposed to more common scenarios where you'll obviously get some inconsistency, but statistically you're ok; therefor repeated clustering is of value. Unlike this case. Hope my point is clearer now for everyone's benefit. Nice answer by the way.

Comment: Ah gotcha...since we're looking at random normal points from the same distribution, there shouldn't be more than one cluster (or that shouldn't be a surprising result). Agreed, and thanks!