What features to extract to cluster text?
I want to make a classifier for text, which is further use to suggest the most similar text for a one given.
The flow of the app is the following:

extract the main 10 topics from the text, using a llm (it can choose from a 150 words pool)
I make the word vector a binary vector, basically working in a 150 dimensional space, where each text have a coordinate like this [1, 0, 1, ..., 0]
then I find the closest neighbour (I want to extend to 3-5, but for simplicity, let's assume it is only one) using cosine distance
I receive the closest text

The problem is that the texts are pretty different, and the llm gives the topics pretty well, but the suggested texts are not exactly what I was expecting. I tried to order the topics based on importance and make the vector non-binary ([10, 0, 0, 9, ..., 1]), but that didn't seem to help a lot.
I was wondering wheter this approach is not good for my problem, or if I should use other parameters or anything else for grouping my texts.

If you are already using LLMs this means you need a lot of compute power, so it does not seem like a good idea to me to then circle back to a simple binary vector and use that for the actual clustering, since you might have a lot of information loss from that step compared to how well the LLM actually encoded the semantics.
It would probably be much more efficient to either use something like SentenceTransformers for embedding + k-Means Clustering if you just want clusters/groups or use something like FAISS to efficiently create and perform similarity search in a vector database (a database of all embedded documents). If the latter is too much of a hassle you can also just use any library that allows you to calculate similarity metrics between vectors and apply this to the (normalized) embedded documents.

I mean, I choose to use llms out of other options. I'm pretty new to nlp, and if I knew a better solution to find relative documents from a database I would use it. The problem is, that this methods was the recommandation that I received and at first it was the best solution. If you know any other solutions that will fit my case, I would try them.

The problem with the provided links is that for my use case, I need to relate as much as posible on libraries, and implement the methods by myself as much as possible. I know that llms don't count, so that why I used them. The library provided abstract too much things and even if they help me out provide a solution, it wouldn't be taken in account.

I see, I mean at the end of the day, all the LLM does in your case is to convert a text/document/sentence to a high-dimensional semantic embedding. The part afterwards, e.g. k-Means clustering of the vectors is actually very easy to fully code yourself, check out e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53508331/simple-k-means-algorithm-in-python (if NumPy is okay; pure Python is also possible).

So what you could do is first use some very basic approach to encode each document to a vector, e.g. TF-IDF, which can also be done in pure python, see https://github.com/geekan/pytfidf/blob/master/tfidf.py, then apply the k-Means to it. You can do the entire thing with just NumPy or even in pure Python. Just be aware that this is very basic and won't come close to the clustering quality of a more modern LLM-based clustering approach. If you're allowed to use llm in the way you described that would surely improve the quality but still be worse than the full LLM-approach.

can you further explain what do you mean by ‘full LLM’ approach?

And also, how to improve/fully developed my idea with using ‘LLM’ as an text embedding. Because after processing all the documents and extract the features, I don’t know how to leverage the prediction.

By "full LLM" I just mean an approach that directly uses the vectors produced by a transformer model (of course this is then again put into some basic method like k-Means or vector similarity search)

To help you improve using the LLM to extract the topics I would need more details on how you are currently doing that. Are you using a chat-based model plus a prompt? Or are you doing some kind of classification task?

I iterate over all documents, and using a local LLM with Jan client, I am using a template promt, in which I ask the model to categorize the document in a predifined 150 tags. Then I embed the tags in a 150d vector and after that I use the similarity search on them to be able to find the best fit. So yeah, that is the reaseon why I asked, cause I don't understand what can be improved

Isn't this approach the best in term of generating the embeded vectors, cause from what I have searched, LLMs are above any NLP algorithm?
In case that you have something better, I can try it.

I am sure it will produce something reasonable if the underlying instruction model is strong enough, although it might be a little bit of an unconventional approach. First of all you "hardcode" the 150 classes. When this is done it would be a more traditional approach is to do something like a multiclass text classification with 150 classes, which you then either have training data for or do it as zero-shot classification. This would also allow you to have a more fine-grained score per class (e.g. a number between 0.0 and 1.0 instead of exactly 0 or 1).

But since your end goal is to find similar documents, this hardcoding of classes seems unnecessary, the model can probably distinguish between documents better if you let it use its own semantic embeddings it learned during pretraining. This is where SentenceTransformers and k-Means/similarity search could come in: You let the model represent the document in a highdimensional vector space and then just use k-Means clustering or a basic similarity search to work directly with the model representations. This way you avoid the information loss you might encounter because of the class hardcoding.

So the problem is that I don't train a model to fit my data, I just use a prompt to ask a GPT to categorize the documents. The need for a hardcoded classes was derived from 2 problems:

I can't use its predictibility cause it would generate so much information, which then I have to group into specific topics or anything related, so using the hardcoded I can then transform the vector to its embeding, by simple cheking the classes present
The result will be generated faster, anyway than letting it guess, and more than that applying scoring to make it continous rather than discrete


So in my case, of using a GPT LLM, the normal approach, at least for me, was to ask it to generate the classes for each document, and then embed them. I can t use a relative scoring or a history cause I have too much domunts and probably the response time will increase exponantially. Plus the memory of the LLM its limited too

Having that said, do you belive that it can be a better aproach rather than asking the GPT to predict the topics for each document? I understand the part with the k-means or any other similarity metric, I just wonder how I can come to the embeding to maximize the chances of predicting a very related document, using of course a LLM

I feel like the question whether an embedding approach works better than your heuristic approach depends on how similar or dissimilar your texts are. If they are very dissimilar, your topic vectors might be sufficiently different from each other. If they are very similar and nuances decide how two texts relate to each other, your approach might fail.

E.g. if you have two sentences "Germans like to travel by bus." and "German people do not like to use public busses." and the topics [Germany, ..., Public Transportation], for both your sentences you might end up with [1, 0, ..., 0, 1]. Then your heuristic is oversimplifying, while the model embeddings might still catch the semantic difference between the two cases (the semantics are not exactly the same as one is the opposite of the other).

As for the practical implementation, if you are using e.g. the OpenAI API you could get those embeddings using one of their embedding models (https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/embeddings/embedding-models). Other than that you can of course use SentenceTransformers, which is also very straightforward (https://sbert.net/examples/applications/computing-embeddings/README.html)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

sure, I have already tried the transformers sentances and it seems to work
I will continue on the thread provided
